# PHP location header absolute path

Tags: php, http, url, header

Because `header("Location: ");` header needs to be used with absolute paths rather then relative ones, I made up this function to get a absolute path by using the `$_SERVER` variables.

```
function getAbsolutePath($relativePath = "/site/123/") {
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $protocol = 'https'; 
} else {
    $protocol = 'http';
}

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];

$absolutePath = 'Location: ' . $protocol . "://" . $host  . ":" . $port . $relativepath;
return $absolutePath;
}
```

Is this the perfect method to do so, or are they any *better* alternatives?

Comment: `"/site/123/"` is not a relative path. It will start from root directory.

Comment: @PLB I think the OP really means full host+protocol vs just a relative path.  The full host technically _is_ required by the spec, though few people around here on SO tend to use it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: From HTTP 1.1 _absolute URIs always begin with a scheme name followed by a colon._

Comment: Yep, that's it. According to the HTTP 1.1 RFC's, `/site/123/` is not a absolute path.

Comment: Zulakis, it's not an an (absolute) URI, but it certainly is an absolute path.

Comment: @JulianReschke You are correct, I wanted to edit it but it was too late :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "textbook" way of making an absolute URI.

A few caveats I would like to highlight.

1. `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` may not always be defined; the condition of `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443` should be inspected in that case; if you're behind a HTTPS load balancer that forwards the traffic via HTTP and none of the aforementioned methods work, you may have to hard code it.
2. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not always defined either; this happens rarely, `HTTP/0.9` didn't define it and some home brew HTTP scripts may not pass it. You could look at `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to find an alternative.
3. If the protocol and port is `http, 80` or `https, 443` respectively, you don't need to add `:$port`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is ok. I don't think you can do this in an other way.

Comment: Always use references to support your answer, don't use notions like "I think/I suppose" they makes no conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute path in the Location header field is fine. Don't worry about making it a full URI. See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/185 and http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21.html#header.location